# How do I take Input string from user instead of the example and then Count spaces, punctuation, digits, and letters. C++

Tags: c++

This is my code.
User will give an input(any string) instead of the "This is a test. 1 2 3 4 5".

Then it will show number of spaces, punctuation, digits, and letters as output string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main() {

const char *str = "This is a test. 1 2 3 4 5";
int letters = 0, spaces = 0, punct = 0, digits = 0;

cout << str << endl;
while(*str) {
if(isalpha(*str)) 
   ++letters;
else if(isspace(*str)) 
   ++spaces;
else if(ispunct(*str)) 
   ++punct;
else if(isdigit(*str)) 
   ++digits;
++str;
}
cout << "Letters: " << letters << endl;
cout << "Digits: " << digits << endl;
cout << "Spaces: " << spaces << endl;
cout << "Punctuation: " << punct << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the question, or what do you perceive as wrong with your code?

Comment: @SteveLorimer That won't work as intended. OP should use `std::getline()` instead.

Comment: @user0042 my bad, you are correct - you need to use a combination of `std::getline` and `std::cin` - answer updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in conjunction with [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) which reads from the standard C input stream [stdin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c)

- `std::getline` reads characters from an input stream and places them into a string
- `std::cin` is the input stream associated with `stdin`

Typically you want to output a prompt to the user:

```
std::cout << "Please enter your test input:\n";
```

Then you want to create a `std::string`, and use `std::getline` with `std::cin` to store the user's input into that string:

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

At this point your program will block until the user types in their input, and presses enter.

Once the user presses enter, `std::getline` will return, and you can do whatever you want with the contents of the string

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the test input:\n";
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    const char *str = input.c_str();
    int letters = 0, spaces = 0, punct = 0, digits = 0;

    cout << str << endl;
    while(*str) {
        if(isalpha(*str))
            ++letters;
        else if(isspace(*str))
            ++spaces;
        else if(ispunct(*str))
            ++punct;
        else if(isdigit(*str))
            ++digits;
        ++str;
    }
    cout << "Letters: " << letters << endl;
    cout << "Digits: " << digits << endl;
    cout << "Spaces: " << spaces << endl;
    cout << "Punctuation: " << punct << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter the test input:
This is a test 1 2 3 4
This is a test 1 2 3 4
Letters: 11
Digits: 4
Spaces: 7
Punctuation: 0
```

Comment: @MoshiurRahman if this answer helped you, please take a moment to accept it (click on the tick to the left of the question)